# Assigning value to a hidden field from a drop down

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I have a form that I'm filling in with an ajax request. Most of that is going along ok but I can't seem to assign the value of a dropdown to a hidden variable.

The idea is this: You select a previously completed assignment, that submits an ajax request and from that request, I'm filling in all of the values of the form.

You also have the option of removing (deleting) this assignment. To do that, I need to get the value of the id (it's returned int he ajax request) and have it filled in to a hidden field. This hidden field is in a different form.  When I try to submit this form, the field is not filled in.

Example Code:

```
function loadQuery() {
    var assign = $("#existingAssignment").val(); // Get the value of the select box so we can build the next page
    $.ajax({
        type: 'get',
        url: 'http://127.0.0.1/WMT/model/getCandidate.cfc',
        data: {
            method: 'getExistingAssignPosInfo',
            tourid: assign
        },
        dataType: 'json',
        async: false,
        success: function (result) {

            $('#removeAssignment').show(); // This is the name of the hidden field. We Show this when we get the JSON
            $('#removeAssignmentID').val(result.DATA[0][0]);

        }
    });
}
```

HTML

```
<form class="form-horizontal" action="">
    <div class="pull-left">
        <input type="submit" id="removeAssignment" class="btn btn-danger" value="Remove Assignment">
        <input type="hidden" name="TheAssignment" id="removeAssignmentID" value="">
    </div>
</form>
```

That is the form that should submit the ID so I will know what to remove. However, when I submit the form, there is no value being set.

Please note: The JS code above might be missing a } or two as it's just an example.

Comment: Of course the hidden input doesn't have a value, you never set one. Doing so is pretty trivial: `$('#removeAssignmentID').val(PosVar);`

Comment: in jquery, asigning a select value to any other element is as easy as `$(document).on("change", "#selectID", function(e) { $("#someInput").val($(this).val()) })`, but you can set that to run always, so its ready when time to post

Comment: Dammit monday.. Sorry I put the wrong code in. Editing...

Comment: @weggie Also, code formatting is hugely important; if your code isn't readable it's less likely for people to want to answer your question. If you don't want to format by hand, use http://jsbeautifier.org/ to handle it for you.

Comment: Thanks @AnthonyGrist fixed, and bookmarked site.

Comment: I'd do a `console.log` of `result` and check that it's returning what you expect.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here you have an example:

```
$("select[name=test]").change(function(){
 $("input[name=hiddenfield]").val($(this).val());
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Wyp8f/

It changes the value of the hidden field with each change of the select field. You can test the code. That's the way of assigning a value to a hidden field from a dropdown. Maybe it can help you.